# how to automate helm deployments in github actions

Tags: kubernetes, github, helm

I've got a private github actions runner with a repo that contains a helm chart for logstash

```
runner@runnerdeploy-elkstack-6pkp9-45kpw:
/runner/_work/elastic-logstash-kibana/elastic-logstash-kibana/elkhelmconfig/logstash$ ls
    Chart.yaml  templates  values.yaml
```

The values.yaml is in elkhelmconfig/logstash

so manually I would go to the elkhelmconfig directory and run

```
helm install logstash logstash/
```

but how to do it from within the private runner automatically?
There is no k8s config and the helm action fails on aws-cli not installed.

Can it be done scripted by curl https://***helm && chmod a+x helm && helm upgrade logstash

or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working with this helm github action

https://github.com/marketplace/actions/helm-3

add secret to github as your .kube/config

and this workflow step:

```
steps:  
      - name: 'check it out'
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: helm-deploy
        uses: WyriHaximus/github-action-helm3@v2.0
        with:
          exec: helm upgrade logstash /github/workspace/elk/logstash/ --install --wait --atomic --namespace=default --set=app.name=logstash --values=/github/workspace/elk/logstash/values.yaml
          kubeconfig: '${{ secrets.KUBECONFIG }}'
```